# How to remove all attributes from element

Tags: python, lxml

How to remove all attributes of the specific elements througout the document. I'm trying something like this:

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit
from lxml import html

content = open("source.html").read()
document = UnicodeDammit(content, is_html=True)
parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding=document.original_encoding)
root = html.document_fromstring(content, parser=parser)

for attr in root.xpath('.//table/@*'):
    del attr.attrib
```

Here I'm trying to delete all attributes from all tables in the document using xpath, but it doesn't work.

Comment: yes, but considering xpath there should something like this: <table class="price">...</table> should become <table>...</table>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one possible way, assuming that you want to remove *all* attributes of certain element, say `table` :

```
for table in root.xpath('//table[@*]'):
    table.attrib.clear()
```

The code above loop through all `table` that contains any attribute, then call `clear()` method of the elemet's `attrib` property, since the property is simply a python dictionary.